# How to measure data transfer speed between my internal SATA HDD and External USB HDD?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, external-hard-drive, speed, sata

How to measure data transfer speed between my internal SATA HDD and External USB HDD?

I purchased new Seegate freego USB HDD but when i copy somthing from internal HDD to USB HDD or viceversa data transfer speed is very slow.

What is max. supported speed in USB to IDE transfer?

Comment: I have never, ever seen a USB to IDE transfer exceed 30-35 MB/sec (Megabytes).  They typically run in the 20-30 MB/sec range and rarely ever exceed even 30 MB/sec.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need anything fancy you can just use the built-in Windows PerfMon.   Use the + to add a performance object of Physical Disk, then select one or more of the counters, like Disk Write Bytes/sec, Disk Read Bytes/sec, or Disk Bytes/sec.  There is an "Explain" button to tell you a little more about each counter.  Copy a large file and watch the graphs.  When you click on one of the counters it will show Last, Average, Minimum, Maximum, and duration values update as the file is copying.

This helped me in the past figure out that my Raptor drive was running at 1/3 of normal speed.  It turned out to be that one of those older, less sturdy SATA jacks on the motherboard was loose.

You can't transfer any faster than the slowest device.
Maximum (not what you will really get) transfer rates:

(megabytes / megabits per sec)
USB 1.1  - 1.5 / 12
USB 2.0  - 60 / 480
PATA/IDE - 133 / 1064 (UDMA ATA 133, there's also older 66 and 100)

A few others
SATA 1   - 150 / 1200
SATA 2   - 300 / 2400
SATA 3   - 600 / 4800
USB 3.0  - 625 / 5000

Edit: See the [List of device bit rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths#Storage) link below from shf301 for a much better chart of storage device transfer rates in bits and bytes.

Some links with screen shots:
[adminfoo.net Windows Perfmon The Top Ten Counters](http://adminfoo.net/2007/04/windows-perfmon-top-ten-counters.html)
[Performance Monitor - Windows Server 2003 Disk counters and logs](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/HealthCheck/Disk_Health.htm)
(yeah, it's for Server 2003, but it covers monitoring and bottlenecks)

Comment: IDE is 66, 100, or 133 Mbytes/sec not Mbits/Sec  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths#Storage

Comment: @shf301 - yeah, I made the correction, but based the revised tranasfer rate on "data transfer rate of about 70 megabytes per second."  from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) to give you an idea of transfer speed. It's not a hard core speed test but potentially a good start. 
It shows the speed in the Title bar